# IllegalArgumentException occured : id to load is required for loading?

Tags: java, playframework, illegalargumentexception

When I try to access the findById it is showing the following:

```
IllegalArgumentException "id to load is required for loading"
```

Here's my code:

```
package controllers;
import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import java.util.*;
import models.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static void index() {

       render();
    }
    public static void saveUser(String name)
    {
        User1 user =new User1(name);
        String res = "";
        if( user.save()!=null){
            res="Stored Successfully";
        }
        else{
            res="Failed to store";
        }
        render(res);
    }
    public static void showUser(Long id)
    {
       User1 user=  User1.findById(id);
       render(user);
    }

}
```

and below is my routes file i don't understand why the error is coming and illegal argument exception.
    # Routes
    # This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
    # ~~~~

```
# Home page
GET     /                                       Application.index

# Ignore favicon requests
GET     /favicon.ico                            404

# Map static resources from the /app/public folder to the /public path
GET     /public/                                staticDir:public

# Catch all
*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}
```

Comment: Would you post `routes` file, please?

Comment: # Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                                       Application.index

# Ignore favicon requests
GET     /favicon.ico                            404

# Map static resources from the /app/public folder to the /public path
GET     /public/                                staticDir:public

# Catch all
*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}

Comment: Yes, I've suggested an edit to make your question easier to read. Please be patient.

Comment: Please take some time to peruse the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 4):

`IllegalArgumentException` is thrown because the id is null. Make sure you pass correct value with the request. Mapping the controller method in `routes` file as follows would prevent from passing null:

`GET /user/{id} Aplication.showUser`

Answer (score 0):

The value of `id` variable that you pass to `User1.findById` is something unacceptable.

Maybe it's a negative number. Read documentation to `User1.findById` to find requirements to the `id` variable.

Try this code to check the value of id before calling `findById(id)`:

```
    public static void showUser(Long id)
    {
       System.out.println("Application,showUser(id = " + id + " );"
       User1 user=  User1.findById(id);
       render(user);
    }
```